# Problem authenticating existing users with new Shiro version

Tags: grails, shiro

I have a Grails application which uses Shiro via a plugin. The original version used Shiro 1.2.2, and I have a very large number of users in a db with encrypted passwords using that version. I have upgraded to the latest version of the plugin, which uses Shiro 1.7.1, and now my attempts to authenticate are failing because of an 'Invalid salt version' error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid salt version
> at org.mindrot.jbcrypt.BCrypt.hashpw(BCrypt.java:659)
> at org.mindrot.jbcrypt.BCrypt.checkpw(BCrypt.java:764)

How can I get my code to encrypt with the same results as before, so that existing users can authenticate OK?

LATER: I see now that the earlier version used SHA-256, so I presume my problem is that CredentialsMatcher is now defaulting to using BCrypt so I need to configure it to use SHA-256 instead?

Comment: Can you share your configuration? What realm are you using, how is it configured? did you need to change anything else when you updated?

Comment: Not easy to share the configuration because it's mainly done by means of a Grails plugin. I think this issue is probably simply down to the CredentialsMatcher now defaulting to using BCrypt with no obvious means of overriding this via settings. But I've got around it by editing the authenticate method in the realm to use SHA-256 instead and it is working for now. I think this is a plugin issue rather than a Shiro issue, in fact.